# Does Spring support PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

A @Stateful EJB can use PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED for reusing the same EntityManager across multiple transactions. This is useful in implementing conversational scopes. Does Spring have any support for this?

Comment: Looks like there are conflicting points of view with no accepted answer.  What is the community/Spring Boot committers response?

Answer (score 0):

There is a short discussion of this in [Implementing DAOs based on plain JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight):

> The `@PersistenceContext` annotation has
>   an optional attribute type, which
>   defaults to
>   `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`.
>   This default is what you need to
>   receive a shared `EntityManager` proxy.
>   The alternative,
>   `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`, is a
>   completely different affair: This
>   results in a so-called extended
>   `EntityManager`, which is not
>   thread-safe and hence must not be used
>   in a concurrently accessed component
>   such as a Spring-managed singleton
>   bean. Extended `EntityManagers` are only
>   supposed to be used in stateful
>   components that, for example, reside
>   in a session, with the lifecycle of
>   the `EntityManager` not tied to a
>   current transaction but rather being
>   completely up to the application.

So no, it doesn't sound like Spring supports them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring supports it. See, for example, [Injection of PersistenceContext with PersistenceContextType EXTENDED](https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-and-persistencecontexttype-extended/).

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a special class with static factory methods for creation of extended entity managers. See [ExtendedEntityManagerCreator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.html)

Also, if you inject an `EntityManagerFactory` and invoke `createEntityManager(SynchronizationType.SYNCHRONIZED)` it will create the entity manager with extended persistence context (it will not automatically detach entities after commit of transaction).